# pyramid pserve in different root path than /

Tags: pyramid, waitress

When pserve starts by default it runs the pyramid application in http://0.0.0.0:6543 however how can I changed it to http://0.0.0.0:6543**/myapp**

In the settings I can change the port but I haven't found elsewhere where to change the root path

Answer (score 1):

In any WSGI application the `environ['SCRIPT_NAME']` is very important here. It defines the root path for all urls in the app. The full path is `environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] + environ['PATH_INFO']`. Assuming you have done things properly in your app (for example `request.route_url(..)` will generate urls using this information) then you can simply remount your application elsewhere (the default `SCRIPT_NAME` is `''`) by instructing it that it should be something else.

There are a couple things you can do based on how you're deploying your application (if it's behind a proxy then things are slightly more complex). Let's assume you're just using a simple pyramid app hosted with waitress. You can move your app using the `rutter`[1] package which will match the `/myapp/*` path and send all requests to your app with the appropriate `SCRIPT_NAME` (`myapp`) and `PATH_INFO`.

The declarative config is the simplest for a pyramid app. Just install `rutter` and then update your INI file to mount your application at `/myapp` prefix:

```
[app:foo]
use = egg:myapp#main

[composite:main]
use = egg:rutter#urlmap
/myapp = foo
```

Note I renamed the `app:main` to `app:foo` because you can only have one wsgi component named `main` and we want it to be the composite.

[1] http://rutter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#declarative-configuration-using-paste-deploy-ini-files